# Postsharp DTO request validation & controller wide validation exception handling

Tags: c#, aop, webapi, postsharp

I'm trying to put PostSharp to use in a WebAPI project. I can't wrap my head around this task. I'd like to use PostSharp contracts to validate incoming DTOs and centralize exception handling in case of validation error. But I don't know how to apply exception aspect at class level, and even worse how to return an JSON error response when this happens.

Comment: Which platform are you working on? ASP.NET Core? Do you have some code examples of what you're trying to get rid of (how does your current approach look like?)? Have you looked at the documentation and examples about [intercepting method calls](https://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception)?

Comment: The platform is .NET 5.0. I have a Controller for which I want to validate the inputs. For that I used PostSharp Contracts, and the exceptions for invalid requests are being thrown. Just can't seem to catch any because the actual exception is thrown in the setter of the request DTO class, which instantiates in the controller method by the [FromBody] attribute.

Comment: Handling the exception on the controller method doesn't work since the exception is thrown before the controller method is thrown. Search for ".net core handle model binding exception" to find a way to hook into this process.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear without code examples to see what you're trying to use PostSharp for. It seems you're looking for some typical [model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#automatic-short-circuit) in ASP.NET Core (.NET 5) and returning a custom JSON response (assuming you're working with an ASP.NET web API).

I know you're asking about PostSharp, but I believe it requires some custom code to make it work and return custom responses in ASP.NET, while you get much of that for free with ASP itself in the DataAnnotations namespace.

Example:

```cs
// CredentialsRequest.cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class Credentials
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}


// AuthenticationController.cs
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] Credentials credentials)
    {
        var result = // check `credentials` for valid login
        return result.Success
            ? Ok(result)
            : StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, result);
    }
}
```

To catch all model validation errors, you can add the following response factory in `Startup.ConfigureServices` (customize it to your own liking):

```cs
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(config =>
{
    // Override default response when input model is invalid
    config.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory =
        ctx => new BadRequestObjectResult(new BaseResponse(
            success: ctx.ModelState.IsValid,
            errors: ctx.ModelState.Values
                .Where(v => v.ValidationState == ModelValidationState.Invalid)
                .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
                .Select(e => new ErrorDetails
                {
                    Code = "ModelError",
                    Description = e.ErrorMessage
                })
                .ToList()
            ));
});
```

Here `BaseResponse` and `ErrorDetails` are just some simple datamodels/classes I use as a base for all my response datamodels:

```cs
public class BaseResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; }
    public List<ErrorDetails> Errors { get; }

    public BaseResponse(bool success, ErrorDetails error)
        : this(success, new List<ErrorDetails> { error })
    { }

    public BaseResponse(bool success, List<ErrorDetails> errors = null)
    {
        Success = success;
        Errors = errors;
    }
}
```

If you haven't configured your API to return data in a different format it should be JSON by default.

Comment: Thanks @Xerillio for this elaborate example. I know about DataAnnotations, and that's exactly what I want, I just tried to use PostSharp.Patterns.Contracts instead.